# Excel VBA Open .CSV in Notepad and Copy All to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have searched the internet, and can't really seem to find the exact solution that I need.  I have a third party program that generates a report in .csv format.  Unfortunately, when you open the .csv file directly in Excel, the format comes out funky with some data in column A, and some data in column B.  However, if you open the .csv in notepad, and then paste it to Excel, the data comes in fine.  I have the below code which will open the file in Notepad, but have no idea how to select and and copy it into cell A1 in Excel.  Thank you very much in advance for the help.

```
Dim FileToOpen

If MsgBox("Please open the file you wish to import, and be patient.  The macro will take 3-5 minutes to run.", _
    vbOKOnly, "Navigate") = 1 Then

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv")
    FileToOpen = Shell("Notepad.exe " & FileToOpen, 1)
End If
```

Comment: Is the data accurate when you open in Excel, just put into a weird sorting, or does it mess up the data too?

Comment: The data comes in both columns A and B, and there doesn't appear to be any rhyme or reason to it.  Therefore, when I go to do "Text to Columns" it creates a mess with a lot of missing data.

Comment: have you tried looking at what delimiters might be in the file (that you do not expect, perhaps)? That may help you define your delimit on the import or on the Text-to-Columns better.

Comment: All the delimiters are pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you could use SendKeys(sendkeys is unsound if no wait time is used, or other applications interfere):

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ReadText") 'whatever your worksheet is

'your code here

  FileToOpen = Shell("Notepad.exe " & FileToOpen, 1)

  waitTime (2000) 'as an alternative
  AppActivate FileToOpen, False
  Application.SendKeys "^a", True 'sends select all command keys
  waitTime (500)
  Application.SendKeys "^c", True 'sends copy keys
  waitTime (500)
  ws.Activate
  ws.Paste Range("A1")
  ' rest of code

Public Function waitTime(ms As Long)
     Application.Wait Now() + (ms / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)
End Function
```

Comment: That worked.  I had no idea you could code this way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are untested, but I found some ideas [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?3297-Solved-open-notepad-select-all-copy-paste-in-excel):

Try adjusting this:

```
Sub ImportText() 
    Dim Text 
    Dim i As Long 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
     'put your own path below
    Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MYFILE.txt" For Input As #1 
    i = 1 
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
        Input #1, Text 
        Range("a" & i) = Text 
        i = i + 1 
    Loop 
    Close #1 
End Sub
```

(this has also been on [SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373700/how-to-copy-the-text-from-notepad-to-excel))

Or

```
Dim myPlace as Range
Set myPlace = Cells(1,1)
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MYFILE.txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True 
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=myPlace 
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

I don't know if the second will work, as it just imports as delimited, and as you noted above, doesn't look pretty. But I left it in case it does work for some reason.

Comment: I found those, and neither work.  The data gets very messy as noted above.  It really needs to be a "copy then paste" as opposed to a direct open.

Comment: @battery514 - so that first one opens the file in Excel? Not standalone? Hm, I'll keep looking.

Comment: Correct, it opens it in Excel.